# VBA Strange syntax

Tags: vba, syntax

See bellow VBE tells it expects an "=" on line 3 inspite of the fact that `.Add` is a Sub, I don't understant why?

```
1  Sub Set_Params(key As String, value As Variant)
2      Dim Tranasitions as Collection
3      Transitions.Add (value, key)
4  End Sub
```

Comment: You have a space after `Add`.

Comment: I just tested it without that space, :( same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your code doesn't know what `Tranasitions` is, you have a typo in the declaration (the `Dim` line).

So to fix it, fix the declaration:

```
Dim Transitions as Collection
```

And then remove the `()` from the call, you don't use them with subs in VBA (unless you put `Call` in front):

```
Transitions.Add value, key
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, refer to the collection using a consistent name.

Then, use `Call Transitions.Add` etc. or drop the brackets.

Vba has this arcane calling syntax.

Comment: Minus one? I'm correct here. Been doing this for years

Comment: `Call` is an obsolete keyword from an ancient version of the language.

Comment: Actually not. The behaviour is very subtley different. Google it.

Comment: I understand the difference @Bathsheba.

Comment: People still use `Call` in VBA, and I don't see it's worth a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis.

```
Sub Set_Params(key As String, value As Variant)
    Dim Transitions as New Collection
    Transitions.Add value, key
End Sub
```

Also, you have to actually create a new instance of Transitions. 
Oh, and you spelled `Transitions` as `Tranasitions` when you declared it. Turn `Option Explicit` on so that doesn't happen anymore.